# Untag someone from my photos in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

Someone wants me to untag them from certain pictures on my Facebook account.

How do I search for them? I have thousands of pictures so I can't go through them manually.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Graph Search enabled you should be able to do this query

"My photos of Friend Name"

or

`https://www.facebook.com/search/FRIENDID/photos-of/me/photos/intersect`